# How to add list of text to replot in seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, graph, seaborn

I am looking to add labels to a select subet of markers on my relplot made in seaborn. I have no problem labeling all markers but when I create a dataframe with selected labels, it doesn't appear. What am I doing wrong here?

```
dogma_label = dogma.loc[(dogma["logFC"] >= 2.5) | (dogma["logFC"] <= -2.5)]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
sns.set(font_scale = 1.2)
sns.set_style("white")
p1=sns.relplot(
    data=dogma,
    x="N: Welch's T-test Difference NODAL_GFP", y='logFC',
    hue="Protein -log 10(p-value)", size="RNA -log10 (p-value)",
    palette=cmap, sizes=(20, 200))
ax = p1.axes[0,0]
ax.set_xlabel('$ Protein Fold Change Log_2(NODAL/GFP)$',fontsize=16,labelpad=25)
ax.set_ylabel('$ RNA Fold Change Log_2(NODAL/GFP)$',fontsize=16,labelpad=25)
plt.tick_params(labelsize=16)

for idx,row in dogma_label.iterrows():
    x = row["N: Welch's T-test Difference NODAL_GFP"]
    y = row['logFC']
    text = row['Gene']
    ax.text(x+.05,y,text, horizontalalignment='left') 

    # plt.savefig("TYK_CM_Correlation.eps", bbox_inches="tight",dpi=600)
```

Current output:

[image: Relplot not producing labels]

Alternative code also not working:

```
for line in range(0,dogma_label.shape[0]):
p1.text(dogma_label["N: Welch's T-test Difference NODAL_GFP"][line]+0.2, dogma_label["logFC"][line],
         dogma_label.Gene[line], horizontalalignment='left', size='medium', color='black', weight='semibold')
```

**FINAL FIGURE, Solution by: thejahcoop**

[image: Finall Figure]

**CODE SOLUTION**

```
   dogma['abs'] = dogma["N: Welch's T-test Difference NODAL_GFP"].abs()
dogma.sort_values(by=['abs'],inplace=True,ascending=False,ignore_index=True)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
sns.set(font_scale = 1.2)
sns.set_style("white")
p1=sns.scatterplot(
    data=dogma,
    x="N: Welch's T-test Difference NODAL_GFP", y='table.logFC',
    hue="Protein -log 10(p-value)", size="RNA -log10 (p-value)",
    palette=cmap, sizes=(20, 200))
plt.xlabel('$ Protein Fold Change Log_2(NODAL/GFP)$',fontsize=16,labelpad=20)
plt.ylabel('$ RNA Fold Change Log_2(NODAL/GFP)$',fontsize=16,labelpad=20)
plt.tick_params(labelsize=16)
n=0.1
for line in range(0,15):
    n=n+0.2
    p1.text(dogma["N: Welch's T-test Difference NODAL_GFP"][line]+0.2, dogma["table.logFC"][line]-n,
             dogma.Gene[line], horizontalalignment='center', size='small', color='black') 
    
plt.savefig("A2780_Lysate_Correlation.eps", bbox_inches="tight",dpi=600 )
```

Comment: I think your conditioning produces a null set? `(dogma["logFC"] >= 0.5) & (dogma["logFC"] <= -0.5)`

Comment: @mwaskom it should be the outermost points in either direction on the x-axis. I don't think it matters which values I input as I have this function in several alternative visuals.

Comment: Then I think you want OR (`|`), not AND (`&`).

Comment: @mwaskom that just gave me an 0 error. I was able to get it to`for line in range(0,dogma_label.shape[0]):
    p1.text(dogma_label["N: Welch's T-test Difference NODAL_GFP"][line]+0.2, dogma_label["logFC"][line],
             dogma_label.Gene[line], horizontalalignment='left', size='medium', color='black', weight='semibold')` but only works if I use dogma and not dogma_label. I am thinking of sorting dogma(df) based on abs() of logFC and selecting top 15 points to label. I can't figure out a different way.

Comment: added this code to the original question.

Comment: Think for a second about what the line where you define `dogma_label` is saying: you are asking for rows where the `logFC` value is both greater than 2.5 and less than -2.5. How many rows will meet that criterion?

Comment: @mwaskom You're right but adding the | did not fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dogma['abs'] = dogma['logFC'].abs()
dogma.sort_values(by=['abs'],inplace=True,ascending=False,ignore_index=True)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
sns.set(font_scale = 1.2)
sns.set_style("white")
p1=sns.scatterplot(
    data=dogma,
    x="N: Welch's T-test Difference NODAL_GFP", y='logFC',
    hue="Protein -log 10(p-value)", size="RNA -log10 (p-value)",
    palette=cmap, sizes=(20, 200))
ax.set_xlabel('$ Protein Fold Change Log_2(NODAL/GFP)$',fontsize=16,labelpad=25)
ax.set_ylabel('$ RNA Fold Change Log_2(NODAL/GFP)$',fontsize=16,labelpad=25)
plt.tick_params(labelsize=16)
for line in range(0,14):
    p1.text(dogma["N: Welch's T-test Difference NODAL_GFP"][line]+0.2, dogma["logFC"][line],
             dogma.Gene[line], horizontalalignment='left', size='medium', color='black', weight='semibold')
```

Comment: added updated figure to show solution, needed to switch to scatter plot and use absolute values as the threshold for label selection.